# Extensions missing after update

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am trying to update a site from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.4.

I worked through the steps outlined [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html) and it went fine except that my new site doesn't seem to recognize any my extensions. Previously in the System > Configuration menu there were menus in the left-hand bar for 'Capacity Web Solutions', 'Amasty' and 'aHeadworks' but now I just have the basic options (General, Catalogue, Customers, etc).

What have I missed? How do I get Magento to recognize the extensions?

Comment: Are all of your extensions missing or just a few? Are they potentially disabled in System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced? Do the corresponding XML files exist in app/etc/modules? If so, are they set to <active>true</active> within  their XML file? Is there a corresponding entry for your missing extensions within the core_resource table? Finally you can check your app/etc/local.xml file to see if "disable_local_modules" is set to false: <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked document doesn't seem to mention archiving your app/etc/modules directory. You may be missing the XML files for your custom and third party extensions.

Any non core XML files in app/etc/modules will need to be copied to your upgraded codebase.

Comment: That was it. Bit of a crucial step to miss!